# Get Opentok subscriber's video/audio output

Tags: ios, chromecast, opentok

I'm using Opentok library for video calling on an iOS app. When a call has started, I want the subscriber to capture the stream video and audio and send it to a Chromecast.
How can I capture and transform the stream from Opentok's output to get a proper data structure to be sent to the Chromecast?

Comment: (Uncompressed) audio and video can both be extracted by hooking in to the video rendering and audio device drivers for the iOS SDK. Take a look at examples 2 and 3 from https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples - note there is currently no way to disambiguate between audio streams of multiple concurrent subscribers.

Comment: I took a look at these custom drivers but I couldn't find how to capture audio. Could you give me a hint about where to look for it?

Comment: This function is invoked every 20 ms with an audio playback buffer: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/blob/develop/3.Custom-Audio-Driver/External-Audio-Device/OTDefaultAudioDevice.m#L856 - you can intercept the rendering data (PCM samples) here, and send it off to do whatever you please.

Comment: Thanks @gobbals, now I can intercept the PCM samples, I get an error when I invoke the method enqueueBuffer:frames:pts: (AURemoteIO::IOThread EXC_BAD_ACCESS)... I don't even know how to find what's causing this error... any ideas?

Comment: Most likely the buffer you're passing in to audio units is no longer allocated. AU tries to read from the array and throws a segfault for reading into free'd memory. Hard to debug from here, sorry :-(